# Writing an ArrayList of Objects to a file

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

```
public class Inventory implements Serializable {
    ArrayList<Product> productlist;
    File file;

    public Inventory(){
        productlist = new ArrayList<Product>();
        file = new File("build/classes/inventory/inv.ser");

        if(!file.exists()){
            try {
                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                file.createNewFile();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Inventory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }        
        }

        if(file.length() !=0){
            loadFile(file);
        }
    }

    public void addProduct(Product product){
        productlist.add(product);
        saveFile(this.file);
    }

    public void saveFile(File file){                
        try{    
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(productlist);
            out.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");}
           catch(IOException ex){System.out.println("InputException");}                   
    }

    public void loadFile(File file){
            try{

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                productlist=(ArrayList<Product>)in.readObject();
                in.close();
                fis.close();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){ System.out.println("FileNotFoundException"); }
               catch(IOException ex){System.out.println("OutputException");} 
                catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");}

    }
}
```

Does `writeObject()` overwrite the content of the existing file or append the objects to the existing file?

And is it a good idea to serialize an ArrayList of Objects like what i did inside the `saveFile` method?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @kevinlee Don't make your question meaningless by removing parts that have been commented on extensively.

Answer (score 3):

> Does `writeObject()` overwrite the content of the existing file or append the objects to the existing file?

Neither. It writes the *object* to the *underlying stream.* The underlying stream is a serial byte stream that can only be appended to. In this case the underlying stream is backed by an *underlying file*, which has or has not *already* been overwritten, depending on how you constructed the `FileOutputStream.` It has nothing to do with `writeObject()`. In any case you can't successfully append to a file of serialized objects without taking special measures.

> And is it a good idea to serialize an ArrayList of Objects like what i did inside the saveFile method?

Compared to what?

N.B.

1. When you get an exception, print it. Not just some message of your own devising.
2. Creating a file just so you can test it for zero length doesn't make sense.
3. The directory `build/classes/inventory` won't be there at runtime once you stop using the IDE. This is no place to put a file.

Comment: have another question. How should i write the path so that the FileOutputStream will be able to access the file even if i'm not using IDE?

Comment: @kevinlee I've already answered your question, and its repetition in your first comment. Re your second comment, I would use the current directory.

Comment: Just want to verify your answer. ObjectOutputStream.writeObject() will overwrite the existing object inside a file right?

Comment: @kevinlee No, it will write it to the stream. You don't seem to understand what 'stream' means. It can't overwrite anything. There is no `OutputStream` API for it.

Comment: Can you give me the answer on how to get the path of the current directory?

Comment: @kevinlee The current directory is given by `"."`, not that you had asked any such question.

Comment: Sorry, i'm really confused now regarding the FileOutputStream, ObjectOutputStream and writeObject(). Please help me explain on these matters.

Answer (score 0):

You could try **FileUtils** function to write list of object into plane text file.
Please find below URL for reference -

*http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeLines-java.io.File-java.util.Collection-java.lang.String-boolean-*

e.g.
**FileUtils.writeLines(new File(fileToAttach), list);**